# Swift - Create data model from JSON response

Tags: json, swift, key-value

I'm learning Swift lang and one of the things that would be great to hear others input about is "How you handle models from JSON responses"? For example -

I have `User.swift` model:

```
class User: NSObject {
  var user_token:String?
  var email:String?
}
```

and also I would like to use [KeyValueObjectMapping](https://github.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping) as I do in Obj-C projects. Unfortunately this doesn't work here:

```
let parser = DCKeyValueObjectMapping.mapperForClass(User)
let user = parser.parseDictionary(data.objectForKey("user") as NSDictionary) as User
println(user.user_token) // returns nil
```

How do you create your models in Swift?

Comment: There are already a couple of Json libraries written in Swift which you could use. For easy access to the json data: https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON
And for mapping it to objects: https://github.com/cdebortoli/JsonManagedObject-Swift

Comment: David Owens of Microsoft's Office for Mac team has a nice minimal approach here: https://github.com/owensd/json-swift/

Comment: No need to derive from NSObject in Swift.

Comment: Here is another library that does what you are looking for: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: http://www.json4swift.com/invalid.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using code generation to generate models in Swift based on JSON. To that end, I've created a tool at http://www.guideluxe.com/JsonToSwift to make modeling and parsing JSON as easy as possible.

After you've submited a sample JSON object with a class name to the tool, it will generate a corresponding Swift class, as well as any needed subsidiary Swift classes, to represent the structure implied by the sample JSON. Also included are class methods used to populate Swift objects, including one that utilizes the NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData method. The necessary mappings from the NSArray and NSDictionary objects are provided.

After copying the generated code into your project as a Swift class(es), you only need to supply an NSData object containing JSON that matches the sample provided to the tool.

Other than Foundation, there are no dependencies.

Here's how to create an NSData object from a JSON file to test with.

```
let fileUrl: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("JsonFile", withExtension: "json")!
let jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileUrl)!
```

Comment: jsonToSwift is a good start, but not quite there. It should generate individual files to make things less messy. But I guess it works.

Comment: That is one gigantically useful tool, keep it up please. Many thanks

Comment: its generating in old swift syntax

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using [SwiftyJSONModel](https://github.com/alickbass/SwiftyJSONModel) there your model would look something like:

```
import SwiftyJSONModel

class User: NSObject, JSONObjectInitializable {
    enum PropertyKey : String {
        case user_token, email
    }

    var user_token:String?
    var email:String?

    required init(object: JSONObject<PropertyKey>) throws {
        user_token = object.value(for: .user_token)
        email = object.value(for: .email)
    }
}
```

This library has 3 nice things:

1. You don't have to explicitly cast to `String` as library will infer the type
2. You can have non-optional properties and library will tell you which exact field was wrong
3. All the keys to the model are incapsulated in `enum` which gives you auto-complition when you type the keys and guarantees that you cannot access keys, that are not in enum

Comment: I'm using this library. Very nice solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [jsoncafe](http://jsoncafe.com/) easiest and customizable template base model class generator with different framwroks like SwiftyJSON, Codable, Gloss, Simple Swift Class  even you can make your own template

**[jsoncafe.com](http://jsoncafe.com/)**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example code for Model Class and parsing JSON response with out any library.

Model Class

```
class User: NSObject{
     var user_token: String = ""
     var email: String = ""
}
```

Example code to call web-service api and Parsing.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var err: NSError
                var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                //println("Result : \(jsonResult)")
                let model = User()
            model. user_token = jsonResult["user_token"] as NSString
            model. email = jsonResult["email"] as NSString
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more rigorous approach and have access to JSON schemas as meta description for your JSON documents, I wrote a code generator which can handle those (JSON schema, draft 4):

https://github.com/werner77/MappableObjectGenerator

My tools supports basically any programming language, because it is based on code generation templates, but is focussed on ObjectiveC and Swift 4 support right now.

Answer (score 1):

May be its too late.

You can also try using the link
`http://www.json4swift.com/results.php`
Where in you just need to paste the JSON values and it gives you the swift files instead.