# How to save and fetch data from file in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save the response from JSON in a file and fetch from it when the network is not available.  However on trying to fetch idea by disabling the wifi, the app always crashes. Are there any other ways for offline fetching in swift except saving in database??

> This is the error I am getting : **Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x109e22320) to 'NSArray'**

This is what I have done so far:

- Create a model

  ```
  class Directory : NSObject, NSCoding {


      var data : [AnyObject]
      var tid  : String
      var vid  : String
      var name : String
      var imgThumbnail : String
      var imgMedium : String
      var imgLarge : String
      var child : String

      // MARK: Archiving Paths

      init(data:[AnyObject],tid:String,vid:String,name:String,imgThumbnail:String,imgMedium:String,imgLarge:String,child:String) {

          self.data = data ?? []
          self.tid = tid ?? ""
          self.vid = vid ?? ""
          self.name = name ?? ""
          self.imgThumbnail = imgThumbnail ?? ""
          self.imgMedium   = imgMedium ?? ""

          self.imgLarge = imgLarge ?? ""
          self.child = child ?? ""

      }
      // MARK: NSCoding

      func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
          aCoder.encodeObject(data, forKey:Constants.kData)
          aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey:Constants.Directory.kName )
          aCoder.encodeObject(tid, forKey: Constants.Directory.tid)
          aCoder.encodeObject(vid, forKey: Constants.Directory.vid)
          aCoder.encodeObject(imgThumbnail, forKey:Constants.Directory.kImageThumbnail)
          aCoder.encodeObject(imgMedium, forKey: Constants.Directory.kImageMedium)
          aCoder.encodeObject(imgLarge, forKey: Constants.Directory.kImageLarge)
          aCoder.encodeObject(child, forKey: Constants.Directory.kChild)
      }

      required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

          let data = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.kData) as! [AnyObject]
          let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.kName) as! String


          let tid = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.tid) as! String

          let vid = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.vid) as! String
          let imgThumbnail = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.kImageThumbnail) as! String
          let imgMedium = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.kImageMedium) as! String
          let imgLarge = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.kImageLarge) as! String
          let child = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(Constants.Directory.kChild) as! String


          // Must call designated initializer.
          self.init(data:data,tid:tid,vid:vid,name:name,imgThumbnail:imgThumbnail,imgMedium: imgMedium,imgLarge: imgLarge, child: child)
      }
  }
  ```
- Code for saving and loading the data from file

  ```
  class func loadSavedFile(fileName: String) -> AnyObject? {
      let pathString: String = Utility.fetchFilePathString(fileName)
      print("Here the pathString is \(pathString)")
      if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pathString) {
          return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(pathString)!
      } else {
          return "File doesn't exist"
      }
      return ""
  }

  class func saveObject(object: AnyObject, toFile fileName: String) {
      let pathString: String = Utility.fetchFilePathString(fileName)
      NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(object, toFile: pathString)
  }

  class func fetchFilePathString(fileName: String) -> String {
      let pathAray: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.AllDomainsMask, true)
      let pathString = pathAray.last!
      return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString as! String).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).absoluteString
  }
  ```
- Checking for network connection in the view controller

  ```
  var directoryArr  = [Directory]()
  override func viewDidLoad() {

      super.viewDidLoad()

      if Utility.isNetworkReachable() {
          Utility.saveObject([], toFile: Constants.File.kDirectory)
          self.serviceCallDirectory()
      } else {
          self.directorie = (Utility.loadSavedFile(Constants.File.kDirectory) as? [Directory])!
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
  ```
- Service Call

  ```
  func serviceCallDirectory() -> Void {
      let stringUrl = Constants.baseUrl + Constants.kDirectoryUrl
      WebService.getRequestAPI(stringUrl, withSuccess:  {(responseDic, Statusflag,error) in
          if Statusflag {
              self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
              self.tableView.hidden = false

              let tempInfo = responseDic![Constants.kData] as! [AnyObject]
              var imgthumbnail : String = ""
              var imgmedium : String = ""
              var imglarge : String = ""
              var name  : String = ""
              var child : String = ""
              if tempInfo.count != 0 {
                  for info in tempInfo {
                      let tid = info[Constants.Directory.tid] as! String
                      let vid = info[Constants.Directory.vid] as! String
                      if let names = info[Constants.Directory.kName] as? String {
                          name = names
                      }
                      if let childs = info[Constants.Directory.kChild] as? String {
                          child = childs
                      }


                      if let imgthumb = info[Constants.Directory.kImageThumbnail] as? String {

                          imgthumbnail = imgthumb
                      } else {
                          imgthumbnail = ""
                      }
                      if let imgmediumd = info[Constants.Directory.kImageMedium] as? String {

                          imgmedium = imgmediumd
                      } else {
                          imgmedium = ""
                      }


                      if let imglarges = info[Constants.Directory.kImageLarge] as? String {
                          imglarge = imglarges
                      }


                      let myModel = Directory(

                          data: tempInfo,
                          tid: tid,
                          vid: vid,
                          name: name,
                          imgThumbnail: imgthumbnail,
                          imgMedium: imgmedium,
                          imgLarge: "",
                          child: child

                      )


                      self.directorie.append(myModel)
                  }
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Reading JSON File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802580/swift-reading-json-file)

Comment: No that solution is only about reading from json file. I have already done reading from json. What I want to do is save the response in  a file and display it when the network is not reachable.

Comment: I would rather suggest to store data in DB than file. Read JSON while you are online. Convert json and write data to your Model class (Table in DB), And read it when Network is unavailable.

Comment: I have never used database before thus opted for this one as it seemed faster. Is there any tutorial that I can refer to for the database?

Comment: More help :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475917/swift-create-data-model-from-json-response

Comment: Show which line of code fails and the stack trace. In theory there is nothing wrong with your approach of saving and loading a file, you don't need a database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is the only issue, but this code

```
class func loadSavedFile(fileName: String) -> AnyObject? {
    let pathString: String = Utility.fetchFilePathString(fileName)
    print("Here the pathString is \(pathString)")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pathString) {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(pathString)!
    } else {
        return "File doesn't exist"
    }
    return ""
}
```

Either returns an object or a string. That's not very sensible. It should return a success flag or a tuple or use a completion block. When you call this function your code expects to get back an array of directory, which in a number of cases won't happen

```
self.directorie = (Utility.loadSavedFile(Constants.File.kDirectory) as? [Directory])!
```

The error in your question indicates a different kind of data mismatch. You should try not to use `AnyObject`, let swift help you by type checking what you're doing...

Comment: Thanks.. What shall be the best way to handle loadSavedFile function?

Comment: be specific about the return type and use a different mechanism for the data and the status of success (or just make it an optional return and log the issue internally)

Comment: Actually it is directly jumping to the else block

Comment: How can i implement a completion handler in this case? E.g?

Comment: personally i'd have an optional return and just log any issues, then use `if let` when you call it. Check the file path is actually valid if you think you've saved a file already

Comment: doing the if let while calling the loadSavedFile function did the trick. Thank You :)